# Can I use a Verizon FiOS DVR to watch TV on my computer via network?

Tags: tv, video-streaming, fios

My Verizon FiOS DVR is connected to our home network. Is it possible to use it as a tuner for watching (streaming) TV programs (either in real-time or recorded) on my Windows 7 machine, over the home network (possibly, with an additional software)?

If not, is there a Linux setup that will allow this?

Comment: Most of the time the codecs on tv providers devices like this are closed source, the content is often encrypted, so what you want is basically not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The HDMI digital output of the DVR has DRM on it to prevent you from connecting it to a PC, but if your PC has analog video input, you can take an analog video output from the DVR and then view it on the PC, but that's a rare configuration for PCs. Some HPs had analog video cards from the factory, otherwise you'd need to add a card.

---FIOS---DVR===analog video & audio===PC/video interface

There are audio+video to/from CAT5 adapters on the market you can use to transform the signal so it can be sent to other floors. That would require CAT5 floor-to-floor, since the signal the balun outputs is not Ethernet, so I would STRONGLY suggest using plenum rated cable if you haul it through ductwork.

You could also get a TV tuner for http://www.mythbuntu.org/ and watch+record over-the-air TV.

Comment: Thanks. This is not practical, as the computer is on a different floor, which is why I mentioned the network medium. For over-the-air broadcast, there are USB based dongles that let you receive using your Windows machine.

Comment: See revised answer above. The USB dongle of which you speak? Many work with Mythbuntu as well.

Comment: There are several USB tuners in the market. For example, https://www.google.com/search?q=kworld+usb+tv+receiver&client=firefox-a&hs=lqa&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=17mhUqXkLKugsQTXyIGgBw&ved=0CGUQsAQ&biw=1467&bih=621#channel=fflb&q=usb+tv+receiver&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&tbm=isch